# Wald Test & LRT Test

Tags: test

De una población simulada, he extraido muestras bajo 2 enfoques.
Al principio, extraje una muestra con un diseño complejo (configurando el diseño complejo de la muestra) mediante el paquete survey mientras que por otro lado extraje una muestra aleatoria simple. Quiero llevar a cabo la Prueba de Wald y la Prueba LRT para ambas muestras, contrastando algunos parámetros con los que se simuló originalmente la población obtenida.

Este vector de parámetros a contrastar lo he llamado: coeficientesfinal.
1) Después de declarar mi diseño cuando estoy haciendo la función "regTermTest"

regTermTest(reg_compleja_diseno,~IngresoHogar+MiembrosHogar+NivelInstruccion, null= coeficientesfinal[c(1,3,5)],
            method=c("Wald"), lrt.approximation="saddlepoint")

regTermTest(reg_compleja_diseno,~IngresoHogar+MiembrosHogar+NivelInstruccion, null= coeficientesfinal[c(1,3,5)],
            method=c("LRT"), lrt.approximation="saddlepoint")

La primera parte, los resultados de la prueba de Wald son lógicos, pero la segunda (para LRT) resulta lo contrario, es decir con la sintaxis de la prueba de Wald me salen parámetros estimados muy cercanos a los reales mientra que el test LRT no. ** Entonces, ¿Podría estar usando de manera incorrecta la función ?? **

regTermTest(reg_compleja_diseno,~IngresoHogar+MiembrosHogar+NivelInstruccion, null= coeficientesfinal[c(1,3,5)],
            method=c("LRT"), lrt.approximation="saddlepoint")

** 2) Para replicar las mismas pruebas pero para la muestra obtenida por muestreo aleatorio simple, ¿qué funciones debo usar? ** es decir, la prueba de Wald y la prueba LRT.

Quedo atento, de antemano gracias!